# Image interpolation by half pixels move in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, interpolation

I'm using some kind of parallax effect on my website. Products displayed are luxurious products, so the presentation has to be pixel perfect...

At the moment, when products are 'jumping' with a 1 pixel step, it's kind off jumpy...
The first layer moves about 6 pixels depending on the cursor's position. In my [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) I have these kind of results after JavaScript calculations:

```
margin-left: -4.5926544240400666px;
```

Would it be possible, like in the Flash-era, to make browsers interpolate this position instead of rounding to the nearest pixel? So I literally have as many steps as there are mouse-positions instead of six hard steps..

Comment: The cursor can only move in 1px increments. You could use an animation instead of directly setting the margin.

Comment: use ease-in-out in your css for animations. you can set the speed too. Look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transforms to move it by sub-pixels. This is not the best example, but it gives you the idea:

```
div {
    transform: translate(5.5px, 10.5px);
    -ms-transform: translate(50.5x, 10.5px); /* Internet Explorer 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(5.5px, 10.5px); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was on this now, you get what I'm looking for, result in Safari is really nice and smooth, but In firefox it's still rounded to the nearest pixel

Comment: just for reference : http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/